# Pipe error with ngFor in object

Tags: angular, typescript

I use pipe for *ngFor in Object, and when i declare pipe in my component - i've got this error (VS Code) - >

```
[ts] Argument of type '{ selector: string; templateUrl: string; pipes: typeof ObjNgFor[]; providers: typeof TableCompone...' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentMetadataType'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'pipes' does not exist in type 'ComponentMetadataType'
```

this is my component:

```
    import { Component, OnInit, Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

        @Pipe({ name: 'ObjNgFor',  pure: false })
        export class ObjNgFor implements PipeTransform {
            transform(value: any, args: any[] = null): any {
                return Object.keys(value).map(key => Object.assign({ key }, value[key]));
            }
        }

        @Component({
            selector: 'tablecomponent',
            templateUrl: 'app/table.template.html',
            pipes: [ObjNgFor],
            providers: [TableComponentService]
        })
        export class TableComponent implements OnInit {

            lists: any;

            constructor(public _service: TableComponentService) {

            }

        ngOnInit() {
         this._service.getServices()
            .subscribe(lists => this.lists = lists)
            }

        }
```

and this is a part of my template with `*ngFor` direcrive:

```
 <tr *ngFor="let list of lists | ObjNgFor">
                <td>{{ list.name}}</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
 </tr>
```

Comment: Can you have a pipe name that is not exactly the same as class name?

Comment: @Harry Ninh You mean rename pipe or class? its doesnt still working

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With latest angular release you can not use `pipes` and `directives` parameters as `@Component` metadata so remove `pipes` from `@Component` and add it to your modules declaration as below :

```
import { Component, NgModule, OnInit, Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

@Pipe({ name: 'objngfor',  pure: false })
export class ObjNgFor implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: any, args: any[] = null): any {
    return Object.keys(value).map(key => Object.assign({ key }, value[key]));
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'tablecomponent',
  templateUrl: 'app/table.template.html'
})
export class TableComponent implements OnInit {
  lists: any;
  constructor(public _service: TableComponentService) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    this._service.getServices().subscribe(lists => this.lists = lists)
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports     : [HttpModule],
  declarations : [TableComponent,ObjNgFor],
  providers : [TableComponentService]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Comment: Thanks for quick answer! in app.module.ts i add my pipe with this import command: `import { ObjNgFor } from './table.component';`, and declarate `declarations: [ AppComponent, TableComponent, ObjNgFor ]`, and now i have this error -> `ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: Cannot convert undefined or null to object`

Comment: No, from debugger in crome

Comment: yes, from chrome but for which line its giving you the error ?

Comment: Error in app/table.template.html:78:20 caused by: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Comment: what is the code at line 78 in template ? `<tr *ngFor="let list of lists | ObjNgFor">`  ?

Comment: you are getting error because `lists` or `list` value is `null` or `undefined` please check `lists` value first.

Answer (score 0):

Make your pipe name different from pipe class name.

Example:

```
@Pipe({ name: 'objngfor',  pure: false })
```

Instead of

```
@Pipe({    name: 'ObjNgFor',  pure: false })
```

and change your template code like

```
<tr *ngFor="let list of lists | objngfor"> ... </tr>
```

Hope this helps!!!